# How can I use v-for tag to show elements in the data?

Tags: rest, vue.js, web

I am creating ec mock-up, and how can I use v-for tag

developing environment 
Mac, Vue.js, Atom, Server hostname is https://euas.person.ee/

Rigth Now↓[image]

What I want to do is showing Order ID and Option Image for each row like

Order ID | OrderDescription | Action

1              "OptionImage"          Detail Button

[image]

OrderListingVue

```js
<template>
<div class="OrderListing">
  <h2>My Orders</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>OrderId</th>
      <th>OrderDescription</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for="(cart, order) in this.orders" :key="order.id">
      <td>{{order}}</td>
      <td>{{cart}}</td>
      
      <td>
        <b-button variant="dark" :to=" '/orders/' + order">Detail</b-button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>



</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'OrderListing',
  props: {
    order: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      orders: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("https://euas.person.ee/user/orders")
      .then(response => {
        this.orders = response.data;
      });
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
.option-image {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Addition
[image]

ShoppingCartVue↓

```js
<template>
<div class="shopping-cart-page">
  <h2>ShoppingCart</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for="(item, index) in this.items" :key="item.productId + '_' + index">
      <td>
        <img :src="item.optionImage" class="option-image" />
      </td>
      <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.qty }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
      <td>
        <b-button variant="danger" @click="removeItem(index)">Remove</b-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total-row">
      <td>TOTAL:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{ total }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <b-button variant="success" size="lg" @click="orderNow" v-if="this.items.length">Order Now!</b-button>

</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'ShoppingCartPage',
  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$root.$data.cart.items || [];
    },
    total: function() {
      let sum = 0
      for (const item of this.items) {
        sum += item.total
      }
      return sum
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeItem: function(index) {
      if (!this.$root.$data.cart.items) this.$root.$data.cart.items = []
      this.$root.$data.cart.items.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.$root.$data.cart.items);
      this.$root.$data.saveCart();
    },

    orderNow: function() {
      let data = this.$root.$data

      axios.post("https://euas.person.ee/user/carts/" + this.$root.$data.cart.id + "/orders/",
        this.$root.$data.cart).then(function() {
        data.reinitCart();
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
.option-image {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry (2 st OptionImage) is Actually 1st

Comment: Second argument in `v-for` is `index` of the loop, so your `v-for="(cart, order) in this.orders"` is an index. You can't access `index.id`.

Comment: In that case, the number (1,2,3...) is just index, not order.id right?

So, how can I show to orderId? and OptionImage from item data set?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Order is in `cart`. But what `cart` was supposed to be in your code?

Comment: Well, I was not sure about the cart also.

My task said like below
1,POST /user/carts/{cardId}/orders - Creates an order based on given cart id
Payload: JSON contents of the cart

Comment: At first, I tried 

<tr v-for="order in this.orders" :key="order.id">
      <td>{{order}}</td>
      <td>{{optionImage}}</td>
      <td>
        <b-button variant="dark" :to=" '/orders/' + order">Detail</b-button>
      </td>
    </tr>

but it doesn't show OrderId and optionImage.

Comment: You did right with `v-for="(order, index) in orders" :key="order.id"`. Then you can acces properties of `order` as in normal object.

Comment: Where in your data is the `optionImage` stored?

Comment: I have no idea where is the OptionImage saved. I guess inside "item.optionImage" is that.

Comment: In the ShoppingCart.vue↓
after click "order now", order should saved "https://euas.person.ee/user/carts/" + this.$root.$data.cart.id + "/orders/",




orderNow: function() {
      let data = this.$root.$data

      axios.post("https://euas.person.ee/user/carts/" + this.$root.$data.cart.id + "/orders/",
        this.$root.$data.cart).then(function() {
        data.reinitCart();
      })
    }

Comment: It seems to me that each order has multiple items each item with a picture. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Let me add some photo below my question, just a second

Comment: I don't see any `orderID` in the data? just the `items` property.

Comment: What is this picture? Do you want to display single order with all products or all orders with all product in each order?

Comment: Ok, probably I misunderstand my codings, not orderId is not saved, however, is there any way to show OpitionImage in the "OrderDescription" Colum(Something like to show how many items?, how it looks like?)
Sorry for my sloppy explanation.

Comment: But you already did it: `<tr v-for="(item, index) in this.items" :key="item.productId + '_' + index">
      <td>
        <img :src="item.optionImage" class="option-image" />
      </td>...`

Comment: This is correct

Comment: I reckon it is in the shoppingCart not in the MyOrders page.

Comment: Yes its in the cart. Which picture you'd like to add to order if there are many pictures, because each item has a picture? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks, I add another photo below, you can see that "Here should be photos" part would be optionImage Photos.

Comment: POST /user/carts/{cardId}/orders - Creates an order based on given cart id
Payload: JSON contents of the cart, example
{
"items":[
{
"productId":1,
"qty":3,
"optionCode":"OPTION1",
"optionImage":"https://picsum.photos/300/600/?image=1",
"price":99.99,
"total":299.96999999999997
},
GET /user/orders - Returns the array of orders, structure is the same as cart
GET /user/orders/{orderId} Returns specific order, structure is the same as cart

Comment: https://github.com/Kazukafka/ecec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you are looking for something like this:

```
<div v-for="order in orders" :key="order.id">
     <div v-for="item in order.items" :key="item.productId">
         <img :src="item.optionImage" class="option-image" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well. My apologies that I have not understood my question by myself.

For the followers, I will put my codes here,

<tr v-for="(order, index) in this.orders" :key="order.id">
      <td>{{index}}</td>
      <div v-for="item in order.items" :key="item.productId">
         <img :src="item.optionImage" class="option-image" />
     </div>
      <td>
        <b-button variant="dark" :to=" '/orders/' + order">Detail</b-button>
      </td>
    </tr>